# MIPS implementation of selection sort outputting correct values

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, mips, selection-sort

I am attempting to implement selection sort in MIPS. My output occasionally correct, but there are several instances where it is incorrect. Usually it is correct up until some point and after that point the numbers print out unsorted. It also appears to have difficulty with multiple negative numbers.

I believe the issue may be with the swap function but I am not sure. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I am not allowed to use pseudo-instructions, such as bge or move.

Here is my code in the C implementation I'm emulating.

```
.data
    msg1:   .asciiz "The elements sorted in ascending order are:"
            .align 2
    space:  .asciiz " "
                .align 2
    comma:  .asciiz ","
                .align 2
    arr:        .space 80
.text
    MAIN:   

    # Ask for user input and put value in $s1
    addi $v0, $zero, 5      # call service 5 for integer input
    syscall             # read integer
    add $s1, $zero, $v0         # Save $t0 = len

    # Load address for arr
    la $s0, arr             # Pointer to arr goes in $t1

    add $a0, $zero, $s0     # Save arr pointer to $a0
    add $a1, $zero, $s1     # Save len to $a1

    # Ask for user input to fill arr
    jal FILL

    # Sort the list using selection sort
    jal SORT

    # Print list
    jal PRINT

    # Call to end program
    addi $v0, $zero, 10         # system call for exit
    syscall

# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 

FILL: # deal with stack and save
    addi $t0, $zero, 0      # $t0 = counter = 0

FILL_LOOP:
    slt $t1, $t0, $a1       # if(counter < len) continue
    beq $t1, $zero, FILL_RETURN     # if(counter >= len) branch out of loop 

    addi $v0, $zero 5       # call service 5 for integer input
    syscall             # read integer

    addi $t2, $zero, 0      # clear $t2 and set to 0
    add $t2, $zero, $v0         # $t2 holds input integer

    add $t3, $zero, $t0         # $t3 = i
    sll $t3, $t3, 2         # $t3 =  counter * 4
    add $t3, $t3, $a0       # addr of arr[counter]
    sw $t2, 0($t3)          # store values in arr

    addi $t0, $t0, 1        # counter = counter + 1

    j   FILL_LOOP

FILL_RETURN:
    jr $ra              # Return

# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #

SORT:
    addi $sp, $sp, -28  # make space for variables
    sw $a0, 0($sp)      # store $a0 (arr)
    sw $a1, 4($sp)      # store $a1 (len)
    sw $ra, 8($sp)      # store return address
    sw $s0, 12($sp)     # store $s0 ( i )
    sw $s1, 16($sp)     # store $s1 ( j )
    sw $s2, 20($sp)     # store $s2 (tmp)
    sw $s3, 24($sp)     # store $s3 (minIndex)

    addi $s0, $zero, 0  # i = 0
    add $t0, $zero, $a1 # $t0 = len
    addi $t0, $t0, -1   # $t0 = len - 1

FOR_1:
    slt $t1, $s0, $t0   # i < $t0 = len - 1 continue
    beq $t1, $zero, SORT_RETURN # if !(i < len - 1) branch out of loop

    add $s3, $zero, $s0     # minIndex = i
    addi $t1, $s0, 1    # $t1 = i + 1
    add $s1, $zero, $t1     # j = $t1 = i + 1

FOR_2: 
    slt $t1, $s1, $a1   # j < len continue
    beq $t1, $zero, IF_1    # if !(j < len) branch out of loop 

IF_2: # "FIND MIN"

    # get value at arr[ j ] store in $t3
    add $t2, $zero, $s1     # calculate index $t2 = j 
    sll $t2, $t2, 2     # offset = $t2 * 4
    add $t2, $t2, $a0   # add offset to base address
    lw $t3, 0($t2)      # load value at arr[ j ] into $t3

     # get value at arr[minIndex] store in$t5
    add $t4, $zero, $s3     # calculate index $t4 = minIndex
    sll $t4, $t4, 2     # offset = $t4 * 4
    add $t4, $t4, $a0   # add offset to base address
    lw $t5, 0($t4)      # load value at arr[minIndex] into $t5

    slt $t1, $t3, $t5   # if(arr[ j ] < arr[minIndex]) continue
    beq $t1, $zero, LOOP_2  # if !(arr[ j ] < arr[minIndex]) branch out of if stmt
    add $s3, $zero, $s1     # minIndex = j

LOOP_2:
    addi $s1, $s1, 1    # j++
    j FOR_2

IF_1: # "SWAP"
    beq $s3, $s0, LOOP_1    # if(minIndex == i) branch out of if stmt (jump to LOOP_1)


    # tmp = arr[minIndex]
    add $t2, $zero, $s3     # calculate index $t2 = minIndex
    sll $t2, $t2, 2     # offset = $t2 * 4
    add $t2, $t2, $a0   # add offset to base address
    lw $s2, 0($t2)      # $s2 = tmp = arr[minIndex]

    # arr[minIndex] = arr[ i ]
    add $t3, $zero, $s0     # calculate index $t3 = i
    sll $t3, $t3, 2     # offset = $t2 * 4
    add $t3, $t3, $a0   # add offset to base address
    lw $t0, 0($t3)      # $t0 = arr [ i ]

    sw $t0, 0($t2)      # store value at arr[ i ] in arr[minIndex] 

    # arr[ i ] = tmp
    sw $s2, 0($t3)      # store tmp value in arr[ i ]           

LOOP_1:
    addi $s0, $s0, 1    # i++
    j FOR_1 

SORT_RETURN:
    lw $a0, 0($sp)      # Get $a0
    lw $a1, 4($sp)      # Get $a1
    lw $ra, 8($sp)      # Get return address
    lw $s0, 12($sp)     # Get $s0
    lw $s1, 16($sp)     # Get $s1
    lw $s2,  20($sp)    # Get $s2
    lw $s3, 24($sp)     # Get $s3
    addi $sp, $sp 28    # Adjust stack pointer
    jr $ra          # Return

# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #

PRINT:
    addi $t0, $zero, 0  # $t0 = counter = 0
    add $t1, $zero, $a0 # $t1 = arr address pointer

    # Print msg1
    la $s3, msg1
    add $a0, $zero, $s3     # put address of space in $a0 to print
    addi $v0, $zero, 4  # call service 4 to print a string
    syscall         # print string

    # Print a space
    la $s3, space
    add $a0, $zero, $s3     # put address of space in $a0 to print
    addi $v0, $zero, 4  # call service 4 to print a string
    syscall         # print string

PRINT_LOOP:
    slt $t2, $t0, $a1   # if(counter < len) continue
    beq $t2, $zero, PRINT_RETURN # if(counter >= len) branch out of loop 

    add $t3, $zero, $t0     # $t3 = counter
    sll $t3, $t3, 2     # $t3 = counter * 4
    add $t3, $t3, $t1   # $t3 =  addr of arr[counter]

    lw $t4, 0($t3)      # Load value to print
    add $a0, $zero, $t4     # put address of $t4 in $a0 to print

    addi $v0, $zero, 1  # call service 1 to print integer
    syscall         # print integer

    # Check if last array element
    # Skip printing comma and space
    addi $t3, $a1, -1   # $t3 = len - 1
    beq $t3, $t0, PRINT_RETURN # if(at least element)

    # Print a comma
    la $s3, comma
    add $a0, $zero, $s3     # put address of space in $a0 to print
    addi $v0, $zero, 4  # call service 4 to print a string
    syscall         # print string

    # Print a space
    la $s3, space
    add $a0, $zero, $s3     # put address of space in $a0 to print
    addi $v0, $zero, 4  # call service 4 to print a string
    syscall         # print string

    addi $t0, $t0, 1    # counter - counter + 1

    j PRINT_LOOP

PRINT_RETURN:
    jr $ra          # Return
```

C imp

```
  for ( c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ) ; c++ )
  {
     position = c;

  for ( d = c + 1 ; d < n ; d++ )
  {
     if ( array[position] > array[d] )
        position = d;
  }
  if ( position != c )
  {
     swap = array[c];
     array[c] = array[position];
     array[position] = swap;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issued did occur within the swap function. I was reusing $t0 to hold the value at arr[i] and then store that value at arr[minIndex] shown here,

```
 lw $t0, 0($t3)      # $t0 = arr [ i ]
 sw $t0, 0($t2)      # store value at arr[ i ] in arr[minIndex]
```

when further up in my code $t0 had been a variable used in my outer for loop FOR_1 check shown here,

```
  slt $t1, $s0, $t0   # i < $t0 = len - 1 continue
  beq $t1, $zero, SORT_RETURN # if !(i < len - 1) branch out of loop
```

In effect I was modifying $t0 when I shouldn't have which caused me to prematurely quit the sort method resulting in incorrect output.

Below is the corrected code along with additional commenting. There are also modifications to the FILL and PRINT functions to handle saving and restoring variables used by the functions to the stack.

```
.data
msg:    .asciiz "The elements sorted in ascending order are:"
        .align 2        # align string
space:  .asciiz " "
            .align 2        # align string
comma:  .asciiz ","
            .align 2        # align string
arr:        .space 80       # max array length = 20 * 4 bytes 
.text

MAIN:   

    # Ask for user input and put value in $s1
    addi $v0, $zero, 5      # call service 5 for integer input
    syscall             # read integer
    add $s1, $zero, $v0         # Save $s1 = len

    # Load address for arr
    la $s0, arr             # pointer to arr goes in $s0

    add $a0, $zero, $s0     # save arr pointer to $a0
    add $a1, $zero, $s1     # save len to $a1

    # Ask for user input to fill arr
    jal FILL            

    # Sort the list using selection sort
    jal SORT            

    # Print list
    jal PRINT           

    # Call to end program
    addi $v0, $zero, 10         # system call for exit
    syscall             # exit program

# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 

FILL:   
    addi $sp, $sp, -8       # make space on stack
    sw $s0, 0($sp)          # save $s0 (position) on stack
    sw $s1, 4($sp)          # save $s1 (input) on stack
    addi $t0, $zero, 0      # $t0 = 0
    add $s0, $zero, $t0     # initialize $s0 = $t0 = 0

FILL_LOOP:
    slt $t1, $s0, $a1       # if(position < len) continue
    beq $t1, $zero, FILL_RETURN     # if(position >= len) branch out of loop 

    addi $v0, $zero 5       # call service 5 for integer input
    syscall             # read integer

    addi $s1, $zero, 0      # clear $s1 and set to 0
    add $s1, $zero, $v0         # $s1 holds input integer

    add $t3, $zero, $s0         # $t3 = position
    sll $t3, $t3, 2         # $t3 =  position * 4
    add $t3, $t3, $a0       # addr of arr[position]
    sw $s1, 0($t3)          # store value $s1 in arr[position]

    addi $s0, $s0, 1        # position++

    j   FILL_LOOP       

FILL_RETURN:
    lw $s0, 0($sp)          # restore $s0 from stack
    lw $s1, 4($sp)          # restore $s1 from stack
    addi $sp, $sp 8         # adjust stack pointer
    jr $ra              # Return

# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #

SORT:
    addi $sp, $sp, -28      # make space on stack
    sw $a0, 0($sp)          # save $a0 (arr) on stack
    sw $a1, 4($sp)          # save $a1 (len) on stack
    sw $ra, 8($sp)          # save return address on stack
    sw $s0, 12($sp)         # save $s0 ( i ) on stack
    sw $s1, 16($sp)         # save $s1 ( j ) on stack
    sw $s2, 20($sp)         # save $s2 (tmp) on stack
    sw $s3, 24($sp)         # save $s3 (minIndex) on stack

    addi $s0, $zero, 0      # i = 0
    add $t0, $zero, $a1     # $t0 = len
    addi $t0, $t0, -1       # $t0 = len - 1

FOR_1:
    slt $t1, $s0, $t0       # if(i < len - 1) continue
    beq $t1, $zero, SORT_RETURN     # if(i >= len - 1) branch out of loop

    add $s3, $zero, $s0         # minIndex = i
    addi $t1, $s0, 1        # $t1 = i + 1
    add $s1, $zero, $t1         # j = $t1 = i + 1

FOR_2: 
    slt $t1, $s1, $a1       # if(j < len) continue
    beq $t1, $zero, IF_1        # if(j >= len) branch out of loop 

IF_2: # "FIND MIN"

    # get value at arr[ j ] store in $t3
    add $t2, $zero, $s1         # calculate index $t2 = j 
    sll $t2, $t2, 2         # offset = $t2 * 4
    add $t2, $t2, $a0       # add offset to base address
    lw $t3, 0($t2)          # load value at arr[ j ] into $t3

     # get value at arr[minIndex] store in$t5
    add $t4, $zero, $s3         # calculate index $t4 = minIndex
    sll $t4, $t4, 2         # offset = $t4 * 4
    add $t4, $t4, $a0       # add offset to base address
    lw $t5, 0($t4)          # load value at arr[minIndex] into $t5

    slt $t1, $t3, $t5       # if(arr[ j ] < arr[minIndex]) continue
    beq $t1, $zero, LOOP_2      # if(arr[ j ] >= arr[minIndex]) branch out of if stmt
    add $s3, $zero, $s1         # minIndex = j

LOOP_2:
    addi $s1, $s1, 1        # j++
    j FOR_2

IF_1: # "SWAP"
    beq $s3, $s0, LOOP_1        # if(minIndex == i) branch out of if stmt (jump to LOOP_1)

    # tmp = arr[minIndex]
    add $t2, $zero, $s3         # calculate index $t2 = minIndex
    sll $t2, $t2, 2         # offset = $t2 * 4
    add $t2, $t2, $a0       # add offset to base address
    lw $s2, 0($t2)          # $s2 = tmp = arr[minIndex]

    # arr[minIndex] = arr[ i ]
    add $t3, $zero, $s0         # calculate index $t3 = i
    sll $t3, $t3, 2         # offset = $t2 * 4
    add $t3, $t3, $a0       # add offset to base address
    lw $t6, 0($t3)          # $t6 = arr [ i ]

    sw $t6, 0($t2)          # store value at arr[ i ] in arr[minIndex] 

    # arr[ i ] = tmp
    sw $s2, 0($t3)          # store tmp value in arr[ i ]           

LOOP_1:
    addi $s0, $s0, 1        # i++
    j FOR_1 

SORT_RETURN:
    lw $a0, 0($sp)          # restore $a0 from stack
    lw $a1, 4($sp)          # restore $a1 from stack
    lw $ra, 8($sp)          # restore return address from stack
    lw $s0, 12($sp)         # restore $s0 from stack
    lw $s1, 16($sp)         # restore $s1 from stack
    lw $s2,  20($sp)        # restore $s2 from stack
    lw $s3, 24($sp)         # restore $s3 from stack
    addi $sp, $sp 28        # adjust stack pointer
    jr $ra              # Return

# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #

PRINT:
    addi $sp, $sp, -4       # make space on stack
    sw $s0, 0($sp)          # save $s0 (position) on stack
    addi $t0, $zero, 0      # $t0 = 0
    add $s0, $zero, $t0     # initialize $s0 = $t0 = 0

    # Print msg
    la $s3, msg         # load address of msg into $s3
    add $a0, $zero, $s3         # put address of msg in $a0 to print
    addi $v0, $zero, 4      # call service 4 to print a string
    syscall             # print string

    # Print a space
    la $s3, space           # load address of space into $s3
    add $a0, $zero, $s3         # put address of space in $a0 to print
    addi $v0, $zero, 4      # call service 4 to print a string
    syscall             # print string

PRINT_LOOP:
    slt $t2, $s0, $a1       # if(position < len) continue
    beq $t2, $zero, PRINT_RETURN    # if(position >= len) branch out of loop 

    la $a0, arr             # reload arr pointer into $a0

    add $t3, $zero, $s0         # $t3 = position
    sll $t3, $t3, 2         # $t3 = position * 4
    add $t3, $t3, $a0       # $t3 =  address of arr[position]

    lw $t4, 0($t3)          # Load value to print
    add $a0, $zero, $t4         # put address of $t4 in $a0 to print

    addi $v0, $zero, 1      # call service 1 to print integer
    syscall             # print integer

    # Check if last array element
    # Skip printing comma and space
    addi $t3, $a1, -1       # $t3 = len - 1
    beq $t3, $s0, PRINT_RETURN  # if(at last element)

    # Print a comma
    la $s3, comma           # load address of comma into $s3
    add $a0, $zero, $s3         # put address of comma in $a0 to print
    addi $v0, $zero, 4      # call service 4 to print a string
    syscall             # print string

    # Print a space
    la $s3, space           # load address of space into $s3
    add $a0, $zero, $s3         # put address of space in $a0 to print
    addi $v0, $zero, 4      # call service 4 to print a string
    syscall             # print string

    addi $s0, $s0, 1        # position++

    j PRINT_LOOP

PRINT_RETURN:
    lw $s0, 0($sp)          # restore $s0 from stack
    addi $sp, $sp 4         # adjust stack pointer
    jr $ra              # Return
```